# Enabling verbose output during debian preseed installation, namely during software installation

Tags: debian, installation, preseed

During a Debian pre-seed automated installation onto a VM, the output is particularly... well, quiet. There's no transparency into the progress of things, or to even see the Aptitude output during the software installation process - just basic, single-line progress bars.

Is there a way to enable more verbose output during a pre-seeded debian installation?

Answer (score 2):

Enter the Key+Combo Alt+Left or Alt+Right and you will eventually end up at an tty where the Log is Printed. Alt+F1-7 should also Work. I don't know which tty is assigned to which Function. But I think Alt+Left once will Switch to the Log-Output. And all other tty's can be Enabled via Enter to gain a Shell.

Comment: This is a debian preseed environment, so typing anything is strictly off-limits since it's an automated install.

Comment: I just tried it, because i was adding an remote-bash Script in my preseed for additional user-creation with pw-hash and ssh-pubkey... It doesn't matter if you switch the Consoles during Setup. It won't change the outcome in any way. "Hold Alt + two or three Times Left"...

Comment: Just checked for `chvt`, it's not shipped to use it with an early_command...

Answer (score 0):

The most useful methods I've found for getting more verbose details are:

- Add `DEBCONF_DEBUG=5` to your kernel command line to get a lot more detail about what the installer itself is doing
- For `early_command`/`late_command` scripts you can run things with the `log-output` command to send the output of the script to syslog (which will make it appear in the logs on the console)
- For *really* unattended installs where you can't get to the console, you can use `log_host=<ip-address>` on the kernel command line to send the installers logs to a syslog server